# use response result in a component

Tags: angular, http-post

I'm trying to get the boolean result of a post response in a component. I checked the api, it results the right responses (true/false), the `data` has the appr. value, but I'm unable to use this value in an other component.

I have this function in a repository/service class:

```
validateSenderName(name: string) {
this.http.post<boolean>("api/senders/validateSenderName/" + name, null).subscribe(data => { return data; });
```

}

Then I call this function in a component:

```
checkSenderName = (params) => new Promise((resolve) => { resolve(this.repo.validateSenderName(params.value)); });
```

How to solve this?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Michael, I got it worked:

```
checkSenderName = (params) => new Promise((resolve) => {
this.repo.validateSenderName(params.value).subscribe(data => { this.nameAlreadyExists = data; });
resolve(this.nameAlreadyExists);
```

});

Comment: You cannot return in the subscribe. You’ll have to return the http observable itself. Not sure what the promise is doing there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return the observable and subscribe to it in the component. There is no unnecessary need to mix observables and promises here.

Service

```js
validateSenderName(name: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post<boolean>("api/senders/validateSenderName/" + name, null);
}
```

Component

```js
getData(params: any) {
  this.service.validateSenderName(params.value).subscribe(
    data => { this.checkSenderName = data },
    error => {
      // always good practice to handle HTTP errors
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: I need the promise, because the devextreme async validator wants a jquery or a native promise object. But at the end, I managed it.